# Optimize canvas drawing to make a continuous path

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

This is a script for filling canvas' grid squares with red color.
I'm looking for tips how to optimize my script to fill squares continuously, without chopping like here:
[image]

I tried to separate and merge some functions, but can't find a solution.
Here's the [**updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nCpXA/1/) and my code:

---

### HTML:

```
<canvas id="plan" width="501px" height="301px"></canvas>
```

### JavaScript (updated):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('plan');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    wt = canvas.width,
    ht = canvas.height;
var down = false;
var draw = function (e) {};

window.onload = grid();

var oldPos = {
    mX: 0,
    mY: 0
};

var dPos = {
    mX: 0,
    mY: 0
};

var curPos = {
    mX: 0,
    mY: 0
};

draw.to = function (X, Y) {
    oldPos = getMousePos(canvas, e); //update position
    var mposX = X,
        mposY = Y;
    mposX = mposX - mposX % 5;
    mposY = mposY - mposY % 5;
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(mposX + 0.5, mposY + 0.5, 5, 5);
};

draw.single = function (e) {
    oldPos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    var mpos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    mpos.mX = mpos.mX - mpos.mX % 5;
    mpos.mY = mpos.mY - mpos.mY % 5;
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(mpos.mX + 0.5, mpos.mY + 0.5, 5, 5);
};

draw.move = function (e) {
    if (down) {
        curPos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
        dPos.mX = Math.abs(curPos.mX - oldPos.mX); // distance between old & new (delta X)
        dPos.mY = Math.abs(curPos.mY - oldPos.mY); // delta Y
        if (dPos.mX >= 5 || dPos.mY >= 5) { // if the distance is bigger than 5px hz OR 5px vertical
            lightIntermediateSquares(oldPos.mX, oldPos.mY, curPos.mX, curPos.mY); // ^ connect them
        } else {
            draw.single(e); // simple
        }
    }
};

draw.start = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    down = true;
    draw.single(e);
};

draw.stop = function (e) {
    down = false;
};

function lightIntermediateSquares(startX, startY, endX, endY) {
    for (var pct = 0; pct <= 1; pct += 0.03) {
        var dx = endX - startX;
        var dy = endY - startY;
        var X = startX + dx * pct;
        var Y = startY + dy * pct;
        draw.to(X, Y); // is it okay?
    }
}

function grid() {
    context.strokeStyle = "#f0f0f0";
    var h = 2.5,
        p = 2.5;
    context.strokeRect(0.5, 0.5, 5, 5);
    for (i = 0; i < wt; i += p) {
        p *= 2;
        context.drawImage(canvas, p, 0);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ht; i += h) {
        h *= 2;
        context.drawImage(canvas, 0, h);
    }
}

function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        mX: e.clientX - rect.left - 1,
        mY: e.clientY - rect.top - 1
    };
}

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', draw.stop, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', draw.start, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw.move, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', draw.stop, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's how to light the missing squares**

[image]

Calculate a line between the previous mousemove and the current mousemove position.

Then walk that line using interpolation and color any grid squares that the line crosses.

```
        // walk along a line from the last mousemove position
        // to the current mousemove position.
        // Then color any cells we pass over on our walk
        for(var pct=0;pct<=1;pct+=0.06){
              var dx = mouseX-lastX;
              var dy = mouseY-lastY;
              var X = parseInt(lastX + dx*pct);
              var Y = parseInt(lastY + dy*pct);
              if( !(X==lastForX && Y==lastForY) ){ 
                  draw.ColorCell(X,Y); 
              }
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/WvuHL/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;


    var wt = canvas.width;
    var ht = canvas.height;
    var down = false;

    var lastX=-20;
    var lastY=-20;

    var points=[];

    var draw = function (e) {};


    draw.started = false;

    var count;


    function interpolateLine(startX,startY,endX,endY){

        var lastForX;
        var lastForY;
        //
        for(var pct=0;pct<=1;pct+=0.06){
              var dx = endX-startX;
              var dy = endY-startY;
              var X = startX + dx*pct;
              var Y = startY + dy*pct;
              if( !(X==lastForX && Y==lastForY) ){ 
                  draw.ColorCell(X,Y); 
              }
              lastForX=X;
              lastForY=Y;
        }

    }


    draw.ColorCell=function(x,y){
        var rw = x - 1;
        var rh = y - 1;
        rw = rw - rw % 5 + 0.5;
        rh = rh - rh % 5 + 0.5;
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fillRect( rw, rh, 5, 5);
    };


    draw.single = function (e) {
        var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
        draw.ColorCell(mouseX,mouseY);
    };


    // mousemove
    draw.move = function (e) {

        if(!down){return;}

        // get the current mouse position
        var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

        // if we haven't moved off this XY, then don't bother processing further
        if(mouseX==lastX && mouseY==lastY){return;}

        // When running the for-loop below,
        // many iterations will not find a new grid-cell
        // so lastForX/lastForY will let us skip duplicate XY
        var lastForX=lastX;
        var lastForY=lastY;

        // walk along a line from the last mousemove position
        // to the current mousemove position.
        // Then color any cells we pass over on our walk
        for(var pct=0;pct<=1;pct+=0.06){
              var dx = mouseX-lastX;
              var dy = mouseY-lastY;
              var X = parseInt(lastX + dx*pct);
              var Y = parseInt(lastY + dy*pct);
              if( !(X==lastForX && Y==lastForY) ){ 
                  draw.ColorCell(X,Y); 
              }
              lastForX=X;
              lastForY=Y;
        }

        // set this mouse position as starting position for next mousemove
        lastX=mouseX;
        lastY=mouseY;    
    };


    // mousedown
    draw.start = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        lastX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        lastY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
        down = true;
    };


    // mouseup
    draw.stop = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        down = false;
    };


    function grid() {
        context.strokeStyle = "#f0f0f0";
        var h = 2.5;
        var p = 2.5;
        context.strokeRect(0.5, 0.5, 5, 5);
        for (i = 0; i < wt; i += p) {
            p *= 2;
            context.drawImage(canvas, p, 0);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < ht; i += h) {
            h *= 2;
            context.drawImage(canvas, 0, h);
        }
    }


    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', draw.stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', draw.stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', draw.start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('click', draw.single, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw.move, false);

    grid();

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=501 height=301></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ohhhh it took me two hours+ to write that part! Please help me with it a little :/ (I've changed much and I just need to fix one thing). I can't find out why isn't it connecting to the **current** cursor position. It works like a magnet, it snaps to your cursor when you move it close to the place where you stopped. Can you look at [_this?_](http://jsfiddle.net/nCpXA/1/)

Comment: I took your code and integrated the idea to color all grid cells between the last mousemove and the current mousemove.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Perfect. Looks like I will need to start learning jQuery among JavaScript. Thank you.

Comment: Since there are no private messages, can I ask if jQuery is more efficient for web apps than pure JS?

Comment: Yes!  Even though is really “just” javascript, jQuery (JQ) is outstandingly brilliant code and using it leverages that brilliance.  John Resig (the creator) and all the other authors have constantly kept pace with new JS options and efficiencies.  Further, JQ eliminates cross-browser issues so writing scripts becomes all about creating useful apps instead of chasing cross-browser differences.  And if you use CDN, then JQ is probably already cached on the users computer.  If I could only use 1 add-on script, jQuery would absolutely be that one!

Comment: That sounds great. I will definitely go for this. I guess my basic coding knowledge will help me understand it. Cheers!